# Are string literals defined by c++ string class are of type const char[]

Tags: c++, string

Are strings defined as
         **string s="Hello";**
is of type **const char[]** of size 6?

If it is of type **const char[]** then how am I able to do such thing like
         **s[0]='i';** ??

Comment: are you asking for the type of `s` or the type of `"Hello"` ?

Comment: To be clear, string literals and `std::string` are completely different concepts, except that `std::string` was designed to work with string literals. String literals are not defined by `std::string` or it's header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
std::string s = "Hello";
```

the type of the right-hand side is `const char[6]`. The five characters (not including the terminating null character) are copied elsewhere by the `std::string` object's constructor. That is why you are able to modify `s` later.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a string literal is `const char [N]`.

But when you write `string s = "Hello";`, `s` is not a literal. It's simply an object of type `std::string`.

The only literal here is `"Hello"`, thus you can't do `"Hello"[1] = 'a';`.